# How to pass order info to sequelize.js raw query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In sequelize, I can use

```
my_table.findAll({ order: [['datetime', 'desc']] })
```

to query data and order by a column. But when I try to use parameterized raw query like:

```
var input_parameters = {order_column: 'datetime', order: 'desc'};

sequelize.query('select * from my_table order by :order_column :order',     { replacements: input_parameters, type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

It can't return the correct order because
 the order info asc/desc is escaped in the query, the final prepared query is like 'select * from my_table order by 'datetime' 'desc''.

Is there a way to pass order info to raw parameterized query?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the sequelize way, but...what if:

```
let order_column = 'something';
let order = 'DESC';

sequelize.query(`select * from my_table order by ${order_column} ${order}`, { type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

UPDATE:
This is the right answer

```
await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY ? ?',
  {
    replacements: ['something', 'desc'],
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
  }
);
```

This way sequelize still protects you from sql injection.

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work. What is the syntax of ${}? I don't know it.

Comment: That's because you have to change your `'` https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Answer (score 0):

I wondered samething. But I think there's no options in raw query.

So I usually define `class methods` in `model` to use method much sequelize-like follows.

```
/**
 * usage :
 *
 * model.findSomething({
 *   where: whereCondition,
 *   limit: limit,
 *   offset: offset,
 *   order: [
 *     ['col1', 'asc'],
 *     ['col2', 'desc']
 *   ]})
 */
model.findSomething = function ({where, limit, offset, order}) {

  let sql = 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM some_table '

... (build where conditions)

  // build order conditions
  if (order && order.length > 0) {
    let orderBy = ' ORDER BY '
    for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
      if (order[i].length > 0) { // [column] or [column, asc/desc]
        orderBy += (i > 0 ? ', ' : ' ') + order[i].join(' ')
      }
    }
    sql += orderBy
  } else {
    sql += ` ORDER BY comment_group, comment_depth, comments.comment_id`
  }

... (build limit and offset)
}
```

Before you call `sequelize.query`, just build the `sql statement` first.

Too late answer, but I hope this let help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
let order_column = 'something';
let order = 'DESC';

sequelize.query('select * from my_table order by " + order_column +' ' order,     { replacements: input_parameters, type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```